# Changing nginx config to accommodate nodejs how to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, proxy

I have a `nging` php config for a subdomain. i also have `node 5` installed and `pm2`

I'm wondering how to modify the config to have `test.domain.com` proxy to node port 8080 or 3000. I've been trying a [few things](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-centos-7) with no success.

I would like `test.domain.com` to point to the node server rather then to `/usr/share/nginx/html/test`

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name test.domain.com;
    set         $root_path '/usr/share/nginx/html/test';
    root        $root_path;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/test-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/test-error.log error;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        # try_files    $uri =404;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV "testing";
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following nginx config. And put it in `/etc/nginx/servers`. You should be able to proxy pass to node server. Ensure node server is up and running.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name test.domain.com;  

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```